# Map two columns into one on Athena using SerDe properties

Tags: json, hive, amazon-athena, hive-serde, hiveddl

I'm trying to map two columns into one on Athena using JsonSerDe properties.

In this case, I want to map both columns `conversionsRate` and `cr` from jsons 1 and 2 to column `cr_new` (doing like a coalesce).

*json1*

```
{
  "deviceType": "TABLET",
  "day": "2018-10-27",
  "conversionsRate": 0,
  "clicksCount": 3
}
```

*json2*

```
{
  "deviceType": "TABLET",
  "day": "2018-10-29",
  "cr": 2,
  "clicksCount": 5
}
```

The expected result on Athena:

```
|deviceType|day       |cr_new|clicksCount|
|TABLET    |2018-10-27|0     |3          |
|TABLET    |2018-10-29|2     |5          |
```

Is it possible to achieve such a result on athena table mapping using SerDe?

Answer (score 0):

JSON SerDe does not mandate (restrict) that column defined in the table DDL should exist in the JSON record. If there is no such attribute, JSONSerDe will return NULL. So, you can define both columns and apply coalesce in the query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE json_table (
  devicetype      string,
  `day`           date,
  cr              int,
  conversionsrate int,
  clickscount     int
 )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
 LOCATION 's3://bucket/path/'; --JSON files location
                               --make sure JSONs are in separate lines each

select deviceType, `day`, coalesce(conversionsRate ,cr) as cr_new, clicksCount 
  from json_table ;
```

Comment: You can also define a VIEW on top of the table so that users don't need to `coalesce` themselves. Athena VIEW docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-view.html, Presto view docs: https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/create-view.html